# How to get value from script's outer html

Tags: jsoup, document, outerhtml

I have an outer HTML from a script and I need to get a list of cities from inside it.

I've been trying to get it by recovering the script as HTML with this:

```
Document citiesHTML = Jsoup.parse(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/section/script")).getAttribute("outerHTML"));
```

The return from  that line is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
      NCM.Registry.add('PreHomeStatic', 'PreHome_1485892226002', {
        backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
        backgroundImage: '',
        subscriberUrl: '/cliente',
        notSubscriberUrl: '/home', 
        defaultCityName: "sao_paulo",
        defaultCityId: '1366122212339',
        cityNotFoundMessage: 'Os serviços NET não estão disponíveis para sua cidade TEST',
        cityPlaceholder: 'Digite Sua Cidade',
        subscriberLabel: 'Já é <b>cliente NET?</b>',
        footerNote: 'Rodap&eacute;',
        cities: [{"id_wcs":"1374010568098","id":"almirante_tamandare","value":"Almirante Tamandaré","tokens":["almirante","tamandare","Almirante","Tamandaré"]},{"id_wcs":"1374019924528","id":"alvorada","value":"Alvorada"...
```

I need to get that "`cities`" array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that ?

```
    Document doc = // JSoup document

    String html = doc.select("script").html();

    String[] lines = html.split("\n");

    for (String line : lines) {
        if (line.trim().startsWith("cities:")){
            System.out.println(line.replaceFirst("cities:", ""));
        }
    }
```